# expire_action from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have an offline rake job that updates my models. When that happens, I want to expire the :show action for that model.

```
# in lib/models/my_model.rb
after_update :expire_cache
def expire_cache
  expire_action :controller => :my_models, :action => :show, :id => self
end
```

This doesn't work because expire_action isn't available in the model. Calling ActionController.new.expire_action gives me a lot of weird route issues, which is reasonable since none of the route logic is hooked up.

I think the common way to expire_action is with a sweeper, but that doesn't work because my model is not updated through controller actions.

NOTE: I feel like I may be using caching the wrong way since I can't find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an [ActionController Sweeper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping.html). You can find the official Rails documentation on how to implement them [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers), but likely you want something like this:

```
class MyModelSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe MyModel

  def after_update(my_model)
    expire_action :controller => :my_models, :action => :show, :id => my_model
  end

end
```

Comment: My understanding is Sweepers hook into a controller action, and this wouldn't work because the model isn't updated as part of an action. Is that not true?

Comment: Sweepers observe models but also are hooked into controllers (allowing you to expire pages, for example). By doing ```observe MyModel``` the sweeper will watch for changes on the model, and then can expire pages based on those changes, all outside the response stack.

Comment: So if the rails server is running, it will detect changes in the model that's done by a separate offline rake task?

Comment: No, the rake task will perform the changes itself. Because of this you'll need to run the task on the server that Rails is running on, so that it can correctly access the same cache.